# Implementar evento onclick dentro de un TableLayout Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android-studio

Buen día
Me gustaría saber como implementar un evento onclick en la main Activity, ya que mi tabla la tengo definida en otra clase llamada "Tabla":

Clase Tabla:

```
public class Tabla {

    private TableLayout tabla; // Layout donde se pintará la tabla
    private ArrayList<TableRow> filas; // Array de las filas de la tabla
    private Activity actividad;
    private Resources rs;
    private int FILAS, COLUMNAS; // Filas y columnas de nuestra tabla
    /**
     * Constructor de la tabla
     * @param actividad Actividad donde va a estar la tabla
     * @param tabla TableLayout donde se pintará la tabla
     */
    public Tabla(Activity actividad, TableLayout tabla)
    {
        this.actividad = actividad;
        this.tabla = tabla;
        rs = this.actividad.getResources();
        FILAS = COLUMNAS = 0;
        filas = new ArrayList<TableRow>();
    }
    /**
     * Añade la cabecera a la tabla
     * @param recursocabecera Recurso (array) donde se encuentra la cabecera de la tabla
     */
    public void agregarCabecera(int recursocabecera)
    {
        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutCelda;
        TableRow fila = new TableRow(actividad);
        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutFila = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        fila.setLayoutParams(layoutFila);

        String[] arraycabecera = rs.getStringArray(recursocabecera);
        COLUMNAS = arraycabecera.length;

        for(int i = 0; i < arraycabecera.length; i++)
        {
            TextView texto = new TextView(actividad);
            layoutCelda = new TableRow.LayoutParams(obtenerAnchoPixelesTexto(arraycabecera[i]), TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            texto.setText(arraycabecera[i]);
            texto.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            texto.setTextAppearance(actividad, R.style.estilo_celda);
            texto.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabla_celda_cabecera);
            texto.setLayoutParams(layoutCelda);

            fila.addView(texto);
        }

        tabla.addView(fila);
        filas.add(fila);

        FILAS++;
    }

    /**
     * Agrega una fila a la tabla
     * @param elementos Elementos de la fila
     */
    public void agregarFilaTabla(ArrayList<String> elementos)
    {
        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutCelda;
        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutFila = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TableRow fila = new TableRow(actividad);
        fila.setLayoutParams(layoutFila);

        for(int i = 0; i< elementos.size(); i++)
        {
            TextView texto = new TextView(actividad);
            texto.setText(String.valueOf(elementos.get(i)));
            texto.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            texto.setTextAppearance(actividad, R.style.estilo_celda);
            texto.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabla_celda);
            layoutCelda = new TableRow.LayoutParams(obtenerAnchoPixelesTexto(texto.getText().toString()), TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            texto.setLayoutParams(layoutCelda);
            fila.addView(texto);
        }


        fila.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(actividad, "Selección: " + elementos.get(1) + ", " + elementos.get(2) + ", " + elementos.get(3), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        tabla.addView(fila);
        filas.add(fila);

        FILAS++;
    }


    /**
     * Obtiene el ancho en píxeles de un texto en un String
     * @param texto Texto
     * @return Ancho en píxeles del texto
     */
    private int obtenerAnchoPixelesTexto(String texto)
    {
        Paint p = new Paint();
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        p.setTextSize(50);

        p.getTextBounds(texto, 0, texto.length(), bounds);
        return bounds.width();
    }}
```

Y quise implementar el evento dentro del método agregarFilaTabla y funciona, pero no me permite mandar mediante ese evento onClick a otra actividad ni por ende, parámetros, es decir, en el main mando llamar la cabecera y la fila cada que se inserte una nueva, y el Toast que puse dentro del metodo AgregarFilaTabla me da lo que necesito, pero quiero obtener esos datos en mi clase "MainActivity" para obtener los datos de la fila que yo seleccioné y mandarlas a un activity nuevo

Este es la clase Main:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Tabla tabla = new Tabla(this, (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabla));
        tabla.agregarCabecera(R.array.cabecera_tabla);


        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        }

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,conn.conecta(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try {
            String SQL_Login = "SELECT ...";
            Statement st = conn.conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(SQL_Login);

            while(rs.next()){
                ArrayList<String> elementos = new ArrayList<String>();
                elementos.add(rs.getString(1));
                elementos.add(rs.getString(2));
                elementos.add(rs.getString(3));
                elementos.add(rs.getString(4));
                elementos.add(rs.getString(5));
                elementos.add(rs.getString(6));
                tabla.agregarFilaTabla(elementos);
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error al listar los datos: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Podrían ayudarme?, necesito que mediante un evento on click de la fila de la tabla obtenga el id para luego mandar los datos de ese id a otra actividad
Se los agradezco
Saludos